# How to Convert Application.app from iOS only compatible to macOS compatible?

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave, ios12, iphone-6

Dear guys i want to install iOS application on my mac. I already have it on 'applicationonios.app' on my finder. As i open it, the mac says "You have macOS 10.14.4. The application requires macOS 11.0 or later." (of course, it's an iOS compatible app). Now I want to open that .app application on my mac. How should i do?

I have tried to edit the version checking, by editing the 'info.plist' on it. But after i did it, it says "sorry, this application is not compatible with this kind of mac". I have tried the version checking on the code, but seems I edited the incorrect 'info.plist'. After that i looked on other info.plist and it seems that i should edit that one.

How can I change and manipulate the iOS app's compatibility, so I can run the iOS app on my mac?

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>appname</string>
<key>DTSDKName</key>
<string>MacOS10.0</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your selected photo will be uploaded upon creating a post, but you may choose not to allow us to access it.</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly run iOS apps on a Mac. You have to make a Mac version of the app.

Apple added the Catalyst framework in macOS 10.15 to let developers convert their iPad apps to Mac. Catalyst is the easiest way for you to make a Mac version of your app.